# loop to reduce writing many form containers

Tags: php, forms, loops, input, label

I have 12 forms that need to be in my page, however they don't really differ that much, for example:

```
<label>Player 1*</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p1-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text"/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p1-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p1-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" />
</div>

<label>Player 2*</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p2-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p2-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p2-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" />
</div>
```

As you can see the forms do not differ much. The only differences:
labels increment(Player 1*, Player 2*, Player 3* and etc. the asterisk is for labels 1 to 5), input name increments (h-p1-fn, h-p2-fn and so on).

How can i reduce this code, maybe using a loop? All of this is in a .php file, so it would be better if it were an  loop.

Comment: What stops you from using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
?>
<label>Player <?php echo $i; ?>*</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text"/> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want can be achieved with this code

```
$cnt=1;

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
echo '
<label>Player .'$cnt'.*</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p.'$cnt'.-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p.'$cnt'.-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="h-p.'$cnt'.-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" />
</div>';
$cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Your quotes and concatenation signs are the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
    ?>
    <label>Player<?php echo $i ?>*</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="h-p<?php echo $i; ?>-nr" placeholder="Number" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" />
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: You have some extra `.` before and after the PHP opening and closing tags.